# Converting simple logic using filter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to ES6 features and trying to apply filter logic in my code. My current code with forEach works but I am applying filter something like below:

```
export function filterContactList(itemArray: any[]) {
const list = [];
if (itemArray.length > 0) {
itemArray.forEach(item => {
  if (contactIds.includes(item.id)) {
    list.push(item);
  }
});
}
return list;
}
```

// what I am trying to replace with:

```
itemArray(item => contactIds.includes(item.id))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` function works by creating a new array containing only the elements that pass your conditions.

```
let list = itemArray.filter(item => contactIds.includes(item.id));
```

This will create a new array named `list` which contains elements from `itemArray` that pass the condition you set.

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the array.

```
return itemArray.filter(item => contactIds.includes(item.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactIds = "test";
function filterContactList(itemArray: any[]) {
return itemArray.filter(item => contactIds.includes(item.id));
}
```

Comment: why are you using typescript(?) in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

All are working fine but as per my knowledge includes and filter will not work for IE.

so we can replace with custom filter function.

```
var customFilter = function (itemArray, contactIds) {
           var list = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
                var item=itemArray[i];
                if (contactIds.indexOf(item.id)>-1) {
                    list.push(item);
                }
            }
   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()` method of array which will create a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function like this:

```js
function filterContactList(itemArray){
   const contactIds = [1,2,3];
   return itemArray.filter(item => contactIds.includes(item.id));

}
console.log(filterContactList([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]));
```